# Docker CI/CD setup with GitHub Actions runner – can't find ca.pem

Tags: node.js, docker, github-actions

My goal is to use GitHub Actions with the following workflow to have it build Docker image with Node.js app on my remote Ubuntu server on push event.

All the secrets are correctly set on GitHub and it seems this is some kind of problem with the runner certificates.

I am trying to run GitHub Actions with it and this is the workflow file:

```yaml
name: Remote Deploy

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Npm Install
        run: npm i
      - name: Configure SSH connection
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          ssh-keyscan -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }} -t rsa ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /dev/null
          ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}"
      - name: Deploy
        run: npm run deploy
        env:
          DOCKER_HOST: ssh://${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
```

This results in the following error:

```
>Run npm run deploy
> deploy
> npm run deploy:docker-build && npm run deploy:stop-container && npm run deploy:remove-container && npm run deploy:start-container
> deploy:docker-build
> docker build . -t test-server
ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/_ping": command [ssh -l *** -p *** -- *** docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 255, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=***@***: Permission denied (publickey).
```

When the env `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1` is specified the runner complains:

```
>Run npm run deploy
> deploy
> npm run deploy:docker-build && npm run deploy:stop-container && npm run deploy:remove-container && npm run deploy:start-container
> deploy:docker-build
> docker build . -t test-server

ERROR: open /home/runner/.docker/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

How to configure the runner correctly so it can build the Docker image through ssh?

Comment: Why not build the container _in the workflow_, then you only need to push it to some repo and get the live environment to pull the new image (and can test it before you do so).